# How many kinds of Cartesian coordinate of n-dimension euclidean space?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

For example, we only have right-hand and left-hand coordinates when talking about 3-dimension coordinate system.
I guess we will get only 2 whatever n is. The others seem to be isomorphism to left-hand or right-hand through the motion of spin (which keep the metric and included angle unchanged), though in each dimension we have two choices. But how to prove that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you mean by a "kind of coordinate" system in $n$-dimensional Cartesian coordinates. However, what you seem to be talking about is the notion of *orientation*.

In the terms of linear algebra, this is an equivalence relation on ordered bases. Two bases have the same orientation if the transition matrix from one to the other has positive determinant. This gives an equivalence relation (prove). Moreover, there are exactly two equivalence classes. To see this, fix an order basis $B$. Let $B_1, B_2$ be two ordered bases with different orientation than that of $B$. Then, we see that the transition matrix to go from $B_1$ to $B_2$ has positive determinant, since it is the product of the transition matrices $B_1 \to B$ and $B \to B_2$, and the determinant is multiplicative. Hence, $B_1$ and $B_2$ have the same orientation.

So, there are two classes of ordered bases: those equivalent to $B$ and those not equivalent to $B$.

So, if orientation is what you mean by "different kinds of coordinate systems," then this argument proves that there are only two. (Although, you should convince yourself that this notion of orientation with ordered bases formalizes the difference between left and right handed coordinate systems. If that's not clear, I'll be happy to write more)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have considered this for a while but I still can't figure out the relation between the notion of orientation and the right or left handed coordinate. Actually I have never feel geometry or physics meanings when I study algebra.  I will be so grateful if you could tell me more details.